# Don't see messages from one specific sender any longer

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I am having a problem with Messages. Suddenly my iPhone stopped showing messages from a single contact (messages from other contacts are receiving fine). I did tried restarting my iPhone couple of times but this process was not as sufficient as it may.

So can you please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you still send messages to this contact? Does this contact use an iPhone (and an iCloud account) as well or are you basically texting/sending SMS?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the original poster does not need this answer any longer, but I found the answer after having this same problem for months, so perhaps posting here will help others resolve it more quickly. Open your text stream to the sender for whom you are not getting alerts. In the upper right hand corner, you will see a "Details" Link. Click that, and then look for the Do Not Disturb Switch. If that is green (switched on), then you will not receive alerts from that user. The killer thing about this is that you are most likely to accidentally switch this on for someone whom you text often. It is no fun when the only person for whom you don't receive text notifications is the person you most need to hear from, like perhaps a spouse . . .. Glad I got this corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you blocked the sender by mistake. To check if that is the case, you can go to `Settings > Messages > Blocked`.

[image: blocked sender from Apple Support page]

If your contact is there, you can tap `Edit` and unblock him.

It could also be that you are filtering iMessages from people not on your contact list:

> In iOS 8.3 and later, you can filter out iMessages from people who aren't saved in your contacts. Go to Settings > Messages and turn on Filter Unknown Senders. When you open Messages, you'll see a new tab for Unknown Contacts.
>
> When you turn on this option, you won’t get notifications for iMessages from Unknown Senders.

[image: filter unknown iMessages - from Apple Support page]

More info here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229